# Perform mongodb query asynchronously in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, asynchronous

How can I perform MongoDB query asynchronously in PHP?

For mysql we can use

```php
<?php
  mysqli_query ( $link , $query,MYSQLI_ASYNC);
  mysqli::poll ( $read , $error , $reject , $sec,$usec );
  mysqli_reap_async_query ( $link );
```

What about MongoDB?